# Visual studio code breakpoint set to grey color & not working.error(may be excluded because of "justMyCode" option)

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I have set breakpoint in Django core library in visual studio code but when I am starting debugging of my project , those debug point color changed from red to grey & show me notification like below.

`Breakpoint in file excluded by filters.`
`Note: may be excluded because of "justMyCode" option (default == true).`

I have set justmycode value to false from visual code option but still I am not able to set breakpoint.

[image: Notification_msg]

Even I have read SO question related but not able to solve my issue so I have to post my question.

I have tried to set `localroot` & `remoteroot` but not working even.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

are you using a launch configuration to run the debugger? i had the same issue and resolved by adding `"justMyCode": false` inside the launch.json for the proper entry.

Comment: Yes I have tried to change `justMyCode` values but not working.

Comment: sorry if i insist: there's a `justMyCode`setting on workspace and/or user level - i'm not talking about that. Of course, i set that to `false`; _moreover_, i've added a `"justMyCode": false` inside the launch configuration i was using for debugging. that (combined) solved my issue.

Comment: Brilliant!! this works! making vscode work like pycharm is a big task!!

Answer (score 8):

I was only able to add Breakpoints to 3rd party libraries when I set 2 options:

1. on the *launch.json* file:
   add **"justMyCode": false** to the configuration.
2. on *Settings>Features>Debug*
   Turn on the option **Allow Breakpoints Everywhere**
3. **(alternative to 2.)** on the file *settings.json*
   add **"debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere": true**

Tested on: version: 1.63.2

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Have you tried left hand side green button on the top instead of clicking the one on the right? it works for me.

Comment: The steps OP followed to have his questions it is right after this click

Comment: This also is the only way it works for me! The green button the on left works, the white one on the right doesn't. They must use different settings, but I don't understand which.

Comment: I suppose only using this button you debug using the launch.json settings

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `"justMyCode": true` in your debug configuration as this is third-party code which is excluded by default.

Comment: Then if you put in a `print()` statement and/or a call to `breakpoint()` (if your version of Python is new enough), then file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd.

Comment: file a bug means I have never file a bug on github.com so can you please guide me how to file a bug. I have checked above github link but still not able to find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://windowsquestions.com/2020/10/04/cant-set-breakpoint-in-imported-module-visual-studio-community-2019-python-project/

Tools –> Options –> Python –> Debugging –> Check : “Enable debugging of the Python standard library”

Comment: Site no longer exists, and I think the instructions are for a different product (Visual Studio Community, not VS Code)

Comment: @Holly - You are correct, this answer is for Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code. Thank you for pointing out my mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you work with Typescript, and have tsconfig.json file --> Try setting:

"sourceMap": true

That worked for me

[Source Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIVHh.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you please replace your image link by backtick-formatted code?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70917357/2475775 I had to

3. Set `"purpose": ["debug-test"]` in `launch.json` to set which config was used.

   source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_purpose

   > Setting the option to debug-test, defines that the configuration should be used when debugging tests in VS Code.
4. Delete `.cpython-39-darwin.so` files.

   One of the external libraries I was using had `.cpython-39-darwin.so` versions of the python files. I suspect these are compiled Python files and it was using them instead of the `.py` files, and thus not seeing the breakpoints. I deleted them with

   ```
   cd path/to/site-packages/problem-package/
   find . -name '*.so'  # to see if the files exist
   find . -name '*.so' -delete  # to delete the .so files
   ```

I was using VS Code 1.77.3 on OSX 13.3.1

Answer (score 0):

**.NET Core Solution**

In my case none of the solutions above worked. VSCode suggested to add this line to my **launch.json** inside the related config which fixed the issue.

```
"requireExactSource": false
```

Complete config:

```
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "requireExactSource": false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

1. Rename file (package I try to debug has name like "pi.py" and in editor it showed "...pi.py is overriding the stdlib module" error. When I tried to debug pi.py straightly (not main file that imports "pi.py"), my breakpoints went greyed out, with message that it was turned off by filters. I copy content of "pi.py" to "pi2.py" file, and on this one breakpoints worked. Sounds like magic.
2. Setting `"justMyCode":false` in launch.json

Also advice, given by **MTex** above is useful.